# IE8 log file?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Is there a way to turn on logging for IE?

I'm attempting to trouble shoot an IE8 information bar message that appears for my site only when viewing on windows server 2008.

> An add-on for this website failed to
>   run.  Check the security settings in
>   Internet Options for Potential
>   conflicts.

The pages all work as expected and I would like to know which add-on IE thinks failed to run.

The really odd thing is that it randomly appears.  I can navigate through my site and the information bar message will appear on a few random pages, however when I navigate away from those pages and then back the same page the message may or may not appear.

The pages that randomly display the message only use standard html and javascript, there are no add on's to to fail to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check to see if there are any bogus object tags.  Additionally, if you are using jquery 1.3.2 there is a changeset to resolve a very similiar issue.  See http://dev.jquery.com/changeset/6268

Comment: I've pored over the HTML a few times and there are no object tags.  But your comment on jquery is promising.  We upgraded to 1.3.1 a while back ... probably around the time this started being an issue.  I'll have to look into it.

Comment: Here's the link to the jQuery ticket.  It describes very closely the same problem I am seeing.
http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4017

Comment: I'm giving you the answer because jquery was the culprit for the information bar randomly displaying.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get some logging going by down loading the [Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=24DA89E9-B581-47B0-B45E-492DD6DA2971&displaylang=en) and running the Internet Explorer Compatibility Test Tool.

I am able to see multiple "[ActiveX Blocking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565667(VS.85).aspx)" events but it's not giving me any details as to what the cause of them are.  It's saying the CLSID is {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} and there's no control url, name or publisher.  I do not have any object object tags in my html.  I'm stumped as to what's causing this and starting to think this is a defect with IE.

FYI - When I attempted to run the Internet Explorer Compatibility Test Tool after installing I got a "[The file size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot be saved](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954368)" error message that required me to install a [hot fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950923/).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem can be found in Server 2008 / Server Manager security information.   You'll need to disable IE ESC ( enhanced security configuration ) via Server 2008 / Server Manager:

- Start, Administrative Tools, Server Manager
- under Server Summary, Security Information  click on Configure IE8 ESC
- click the Disable radio button for both Administrators and Users